# Disable the submit button based on text inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

So i have this function that disables the submit button if the second option is selected.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#estadoTicketSel').change(function () {
                if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'Fechado') {
                    $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#notificaFechado').show();
                } else {
                    $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#notificaFechado').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

However i'm trying that the button get disabled, based on the text that is inside a div. I've tried this without sucess...

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function(){
                var txt = $('#state p').text();
                    if(txt == 'Fechado'){
                        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
                        $('#notificaFechado').show();
                }
         });
      });

 <div id="state"><p>@estadoTicket</p></div>
```

Any thoughts ?

UPDATE:

Fiddle with select box: http://jsfiddle.net/q2VRH/ 
Fiddle reading from the div: http://jsfiddle.net/f3nzk/

So as you can see the fiddles are working, and i've found out that the problem what the value on my database. The value that was passing was something like this:

Fechado                                         .

Thanks everyone for your help.

I will leave the fiddle's here, for someone who needs.
Again thanks.

Comment: can you create the problem fiddle.

Comment: sure just give me some minutes plz

Comment: use attr instead of prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try trimming the text:

```
var txt = $.trim($('#state p').text());
```

[DOCUMENTATION](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

```
if(txt.indexOf('Fechado') > -1){
   //do stuff
}
```

The index will be -1 if the search value never occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/symonsarwar/q2VRH/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#estadoTicketSel').change(function () {
                    if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'Fechado') {
                        $('#submitButton').attr('disabled', true);
                        $('#notificaFechado').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
                        $('#notificaFechado').hide();
                    }
                });
            });
```